# moving card from one pile to another moving item from one array to another javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

FIrstly, no DOM, this is on the serverside.
My question is pretty much identical to: [Elegant technique to move items from one array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648692/elegant-technique-to-move-items-from-one-array-to-another)
Sadly in Javascript there are no queues.

I have a bunch of cards represented as objects in an array called Deck.

I want to move from the Deck to the hand in a clean way. I can use splice and concat to the hand array.

But I would not like to do that all the time. Ideally I would have a function that I can pass in the card object and the destination array:

```
function moveCard (deck[5], hand) {
  // return success
}
```

Or is there a different structure that can better model the data in JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer to do this as a queue you can use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and Array.[shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to use arrays as queues.

For example:

```
var x = [];
x.push("a"); // x = [ "a" ]
x.shift(); // returns "a", x = []
x.push("a"); // x = [ "a" ]
x.push("b"); // x = [ "a", "b" ]
x.shift(); // returns "a", x = [ "b" ]
x.shift(); // returns "b", x = []
```

You could just shift from the deck and push to the hand.